# responsive web app css

Tags: css, responsive-design

I have a unique design that needs to be completely responsive. Most the containers are width:100%; with the exception of some navigations. I have been using css tables pretty plainly to get some easy responsive columns for designs, but now that im trying to implement navs that run accross the top of the screen, rather than just columns, I get a bit stuck on how to use css tables properlly to get the layouts to work...all I know is

```
display: table > for container
display: table-cell > for rows
```

I have the layout I need working (In Chrome, FF doesnt work) in this prototype but the content div does not scroll to show the content. In this prototype, if you look in updated Chrome, I need all containers to stay inplace except for the .content div to scroll.... if this is even possible w/o JS?

layout: http://jsfiddle.net/6Q9QY/2/

Thanks in advance for any help / advice!

Answer (score 0):

something tells me noone saw this post and I dunno why people aren't seeing my recent posts...there are way smarter people answering my older questions than I am. Regardless I figured it out by using extensive amounts of containers

http://jsfiddle.net/cZQUb/1/

```
display:block container inside display:table-cell will allow to scroll and keep site fixed
```